# vb.net create objects in for each loop from partial info in Ienumerable

Tags: vb.net, object-initialization

Summary:I want to create objects in a for each loop.

I have a class - Dashboard, which has some properties - length, height, etc.

This info is contained within an XML document, but my class' properties is only a small subset of the information in the XML.

I have created a Collection of XElement, and I can iterate over these, but how do I create my object on each iteration of the loop?

```
Dim Col_DashBoards As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From XDashboard In XDocument.Load(filename).Descendants("dashboard")
        For Each XDashboard In Col_DashBoards
            'PseudoCode
        Dim Xdashboard.Name as New DashboardClassObject
            Xdashboard.Name.Height = XDashboard.Element("Height").value 
            ...
        Next
```

Comment: Is there a 1 to many (1..*) relationship within your XML to the class you want to create?

Comment: If i understand you correctly, No. There are an unknown number of XElements and they each have a unique name attribute. 1 XML Element will become 1 object

Comment: That sounds like it is a 1 to many relationship? How many `DashboardClassObject` would you expect to create in the above code? What is the loop for otherwise?

Comment: I am opening an XML file that is created via another program, so I dont know how many objects there will be. I could do something like a .Count(), but that would be a runtime thing....

But to answer, there will probably be somewhere between 0 and 50

Comment: Okay... So you'd like to create a collection of `DashboardClassObject`?

Comment: Exactly, but how do i create the individual objects in the collection?
Dim (I Cant Explicitly put the name here b/c it is based on the XML and different in each iteration) as New DashbaordClassObject

Comment: Did this resolve your question?

Comment: Been caught up with other projects, I’ll test it when I have the chance. I think so. I guess I was just confused because I was thinking about it backwards. I wanted to instantiate each object rather than the list of objects. Would it be correct to say that the list instantiates the objects inside the list?

Comment: You could write it as so, but they way it has been answered the object is instantiated and then added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you wish to create a new object based on a subset of data from within an XML document?

The below is a function that will generate a new `DashboardClassObject` for every matching node and populate that object. A list of type `DashboardclassObject` is returned.

```
Public Function GenerateDashBoardFromXML(filename as string) As List(Of DashboardClassObject)
   Dim dashboardList As List(Of DashboardClassObject) = New List(Of DashboardClassObject)()
   Dim Col_DashBoards As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From XDashboard In XDocument.Load(filename)?.Descendants("dashboard")

   For Each XDashboard In Col_DashBoards
       Dim dashboard As DashboardClassObject = New DashboardClassObject () With {
           .Name = XDashboard.Element("Height")?.value 
       }
       dashboardList.Add(dashboard)
   Next

   return dashboardList
End Function
```

It should be noted that Null checking is used here. The below is only populated if the matching element is found. Null coalescing operator is also an option here.

```
.Name = XDashboard.Element("Height")?.value
```